# Unable to Cast from Parent Class to Child Class

Tags: c#

I am trying to cast from a parent class to a child class but I get an InvalidCastException. The child class only has one property of type int. Does anyone know what I need to do?

Comment: It also good to know that, you cannot use explicit casting for base/derive related classes.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

A simple way to downcast in C# is to serialize the parent and then deserialize it into the child.

```
 var serializedParent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parentInstance); 
 Child c  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Child>(serializedParent);
```

I have a simple console app that casts animal into dog, using the above two lines of code over [here](http://dotnetanalysis.blogspot.com/2012/12/c-cast-parent-to-child-c-downcast.html)

Comment: Well, I would hesitate to call this a "downcast".

Comment: Just a note, the variable names aren't the same above.

Comment: I love when someone thinks outside the box and silences the people telling the OP that it can't be done (save for one or two trolls)! Thanks for the assist on this one. I've been trying to figure this out for the last couple of hours :)

Comment: This is an excellent solution.  I had a case where my child class was just a wrapper for a parent with no additional functionality.  I did that so I didn't have to import the web reference into my application since it was in my helper library.  This allowed me to convert the parent to my wrapper class.  Thank you!

Comment: You are a genius! :)

Comment: This works very well for simple class objects. Your mileage may vary for more complex objects (especially ones with circular references).

Comment: I wonder how many times slower serializing like this is compared to creating a new instance of the derived type and assigning its properties from the  the base class's properties is.

Comment: Great solution.  It would be nice if this could be done automatically when the child class doesn't add any members (only methods).

Comment: I was searching the whole day for this solution. Great solution.

Comment: Лучшая работа в мире!

Comment: I would be seriously concerned about performance. Therefore I would suggest to use AutoMapper or any other mapping tool instead of this approach.

Comment: very very good answer

Comment: I still think the word "cast" does not apply here. I still think this is a trick or workaround to a design issue. Easier than this answer is to not work with objects at all and erase the strong typing feature of the language, or to do reflection to copy properties into another object, or to map an object into another. The whole point of working with objects is to respect the paradigm i think. So i believe that's where the "it cannot be done" is coming from.

Answer (score 153):

You can't cast a mammal into a dog - it might be a cat.

You can't cast a food into a sandwich - it might be a cheeseburger.

You can't cast a car into a Ferrari - it might be a Honda, or more specifically, You can't cast a Ferrari 360 Modena to a Ferrari 360 Challange Stradale - there are differnt parts, even though they are both Ferrari 360s.

Comment: Understandable roadblocks, hence the impossibility of actually 'casting' in this manner. But what if he wants a dog that's the same eye color/weight/hair pattern/age, etc as the cat that's being held in the mammal object? Essentially copying the common properties.

Comment: FastAl, this is exactly why we have interfaces. Mammal must implement IMammal and contain eye color, weight etc. Now you can cast both dog and cat to IMammal.

Comment: You can trycast mammal into dog.  If it's a dog, it's a dog.  Otherwise, it becomes null.  "overload" functions can make the impossible conversion from cat to dog possible, if cat has these overloaded functions allowing this.  But it is your job to handle the data-loss and adapt the non-existing data.  Like converting claws to nails, chasing string to chasing ball, etc...

Comment: I think the examples are a bit extreme and selective and perhaps the cast is a shortcut for a copy constructor.  For example, being building a ferrari with the properties defined in base object car.  Or, start with a human and create a Boy.  Casting and direct use?  Agree that's a no-no.  But if it's part of constructor or something, could work.  The serialization answer below is a nice touch.

Comment: You may be looking to a scenario where you need a copy constructor, a converter class or an adapter/wrapper pattern applied?

Comment: Ferrari analogy NICE

Comment: This becomes less obvious when you use inheritance as a specialization. I.e .: only a single line on inheritance instead of a tree. E.g .: SuperHero, a subclass of Hero -> there is no other class that can sublass Hero, but it's useful for SuperHero to be a sublass of Hero as it can have other powers and caracteristics. It could be convenient to be able to outclass a standard Hero to a SuperHero when he gots the new powers.

Answer (score 62):

The instance that your base class reference is referring to is not an instance of your child class.  There's nothing wrong.

More specifically:

```
Base derivedInstance = new Derived();
Base baseInstance = new Base();

Derived good = (Derived)derivedInstance; // OK
Derived fail = (Derived)baseInstance; // Throws InvalidCastException
```

For the cast to be successful, the instance that you're downcasting must be an instance of the class that you're downcasting to (or at least, the class you're downcasting to must be within the instance's class hierarchy), otherwise the cast will fail.

Comment: or potentially  Base otherDerived = new OtherDerived(); Derived otherFail = (Derived)otherDerived;

Comment: class Base  { }
    class Derived : Base { }

//In Main Method
Base derivedInstance = new Derived();
            Base baseInstance = new Base();

            Derived good = (Derived)derivedInstance; 
            Derived fail = (Derived)baseInstance; 

This compiles without any error in .NET 3.5. Where is the problem you are saying?

Comment: @pradeeptp:  Of course it builds.  Who said anything about a compilation error?

Answer (score 30):

I have seen most of the people saying **explicit parent to child casting** is not possible, that actually is not true.
Let's take a revised start and try proving it by examples.

As we know in .net all castings have two broad categories.

1. For Value type
2. For Reference type (in your case its reference type)

Reference type has further three main situational cases in which any scenario can lie.

#### Child to Parent (Implicit casting - Always successful)

> **Case 1.** Child to any direct or indirect parent

```
Employee e = new Employee();
Person p = (Person)e; //Allowed
```

#### Parent to Child (Explicit casting - Can be successful)

> **Case 2.** Parent variable holding parent object (Not allowed)

```
Person p = new Person();  // p is true Person object
Employee e = (Employee)p; //Runtime err : InvalidCastException <-------- Yours issue
```

> **Case 3.** Parent variable holding child object (Always Successful)
>
> Note: Because objects has polymorphic nature, it is possible for a variable of a parent class type to hold a child type.

```
Person p = new Employee(); // p actually is Employee
Employee e = (Employee)p; // Casting allowed
```

**Conclusion :** After reading above all, hope it will make sense now like how parent to child conversion is possible(Case 3).

> ### Answer To The Question :
>
> Your answer is 
>   in **case 2**.Where you can see such casting is not allowed by OOP and you are trying to violate one of OOP's basic rule.So always choose safe path.
>
> Further more, to avoid such exceptional situations .net has recommended using [is/as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-safely-cast-by-using-as-and-is-operators) operators those will help you to take informed decisions and provide safe casting.

Comment: I like the clarity of your answer.  Only one issue is the link for the is/as document gives a 404.  Would the following link be what you are referencing?
[Type testing and cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast, "Type testing and cast")

Answer (score 20):

There are some cases when such a cast would make sense.
I my case, I was receiving a BASE class over the network, and I needed more features to it.
So deriving it to handle it on my side with all the bells and whistles I wanted, and casting the received BASE class into the DERIVED one was simply not an option (Throws InvalidCastException of Course)

One practical *think-out-of-the-box* SOLUTION was to declare an EXTENSION Helper class that was NOT inheriting BASE class actually, but INCLUDING IT as a member.

```
public class BaseExtension
{
   Base baseInstance;

   public FakeDerived(Base b)
   {
      baseInstance = b;
   }

   //Helper methods and extensions to Base class added here
}
```

If you have loose coupling and just need a couple of extra features to base class without **REALLY** having an absolute need of derivation, that could be a quick and simple workaround.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you probably want your `BaseExtension` here to at least implement `IBase` such that you can use it in similar contexts? Or wasn't important for your needs?

Comment: some times including can be an appropriate substitution for inheritance

Answer (score 15):

That would violate object oriented principles. I'd say an elegant solution here and elsewhere in the project is using a object mapping framework like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to configure a projection.

Here's a slighty more complex configuration than is neccessary but is flexible enough for most cases:

```
public class BaseToChildMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return "BaseToChildMappingProfile"; }
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<BaseClass, ChildClassOne>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<BaseClass, ChildClassTwo>();
    }
}


public class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile<BaseToChildMappingProfile>();
        });
    }
}
```

When application starts call `AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure()` and then you can project like this:

```
ChildClassOne child = Mapper.Map<BaseClass, ChildClassOne>(baseClass);
```

Properties are mapped by convention so if the class is inherited the property names are exactly the same and mapping is configured automatically. You can add additional properties by tweaking the configuration. See the [documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki) .

Comment: Using Automapper to map a type with a single property to another (like the OP described) is like using a sledge hammer to crack an egg.  Why not just new up the derived type and assign its property yourself (which is 1 line of code).

Answer (score 9):

Paul, you didn't ask 'Can I do it' - I am assuming you want to know *how* to do it!

We had to do this on a project - there are many of classes we set up in a generic fashion just once, then initialize properties specific to derived classes. I use VB so my sample is in VB (tough noogies), but I stole the VB sample from this site which also has a better C# version:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/a4264125-fcb0-4757-9d78-ff541dfbcb56/net-reflection--copy-cl.aspx

Sample code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Diagnostics

Module ClassUtils

    Public Sub CopyProperties(ByVal dst As Object, ByVal src As Object)
        Dim srcProperties() As PropertyInfo = src.GetType.GetProperties
        Dim dstType = dst.GetType

        If srcProperties Is Nothing Or dstType.GetProperties Is Nothing Then
            Return
        End If

        For Each srcProperty As PropertyInfo In srcProperties
            Dim dstProperty As PropertyInfo = dstType.GetProperty(srcProperty.Name)

            If dstProperty IsNot Nothing Then
                If dstProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(srcProperty.PropertyType) = True Then
                    dstProperty.SetValue(dst, srcProperty.GetValue(src, Nothing), Nothing)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module


Module Module1
    Class base_class
        Dim _bval As Integer
        Public Property bval() As Integer
            Get
                Return _bval
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _bval = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
    Class derived_class
        Inherits base_class
        Public _dval As Integer
        Public Property dval() As Integer
            Get
                Return _dval
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                _dval = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
    Sub Main()
        ' NARROWING CONVERSION TEST
        Dim b As New base_class
        b.bval = 10
        Dim d As derived_class
        'd = CType(b, derived_class) ' invalidcast exception 
        'd = DirectCast(b, derived_class) ' invalidcast exception
        'd = TryCast(b, derived_class) ' returns 'nothing' for c
        d = New derived_class
        CopyProperties(d, b)
        d.dval = 20
        Console.WriteLine(b.bval)
        Console.WriteLine(d.bval)
        Console.WriteLine(d.dval)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Of course this isn't really casting. It's creating a new derived object and copying the properties from the parent, leaving the child properties blank. That's all I needed to do and it sounds like its all you need to do. Note it only copies properties, not members (public variables) in the class (but you could extend it to do that if you are for shame exposing public members).

Casting in general creates 2 variables pointing to the same object (mini tutorial here, please don't throw corner case exceptions at me). There are significant ramifications to this (exercise to the reader)!

Of course I have to say why the languague doesn't let you go from base to derive instance, but does the other way. imagine a case where you can take an instance of a winforms textbox (derived) and store it in a variable of type Winforms control. Of course the 'control' can move the object around OK and you can deal with all the 'controll-y' things about the textbox (e.g., top, left, .text properties). The textbox specific stuff (e.g., .multiline) can't be seen without casting the 'control' type variable pointing to the textbox in memory, but it's still there in memory.

Now imagine, you have a control, and you want to case a variable of type textbox to it. The Control in memory is missing 'multiline' and other textboxy things. If you try to reference them, the control won't magically grow a multiline property! The property (look at it like a member variable here, that actually stores a value - because there is on in the textbox instance's memory) *must* exist. Since you are casting, remember, it has to be the same object you're pointing to. Hence it is not a language restriction, it is philosophically impossible to case in such a manner.

Comment: I know this is way after the fact, but you should include "AndAlso dstProperty.CanWrite" to your "If dstProperty IsNot Nothing" test, to make sure its not a readonly property.

Comment: @JamesMLV - thanks good catch. 'after the fact' - doesn't look like the OP is going to accept any answer anyway :-( so there is no fact to be after. Oh well.

Answer (score 4):

The instance of the object should be created using the child class's type, you can't cast a parent type instance to a child type

Answer (score 3):

As of C# 7.0, you can use [the is keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is/) to do this :

With those class defined :

```
class Base { /* Define base class */ }
class Derived : Base { /* Define derived class */ }
```

You can then do somehting like :

```
void Funtion(Base b)
{
    if (b is Derived d)
    {
        /* Do something with d which is now a variable of type Derived */
    }
}
```

Which would be equivalent to :

```
void Funtion(Base b)
{
    Defined d;
    if (b is Derived)
    {
        d = (Defined)b;
        /* Do something with d */
    }
}
```

You could now call :

```
Function(new Derived()); // Will execute code defined in if
```

As well as

```
Function(new Base()); // Won't execute code defined in if
```

That way you can be sure that your downcast will be valid and won't throw an exception !

Comment: You are not actually downcasting anything here, downcast would be if you use your "new Base()", and as you commented "It won't execute". To send a new Derived() is basically call a method that receives a parent, and then you check what type is the derived class... So this approach does not work.

Answer (score 2):

As for me it was enough to copy all property fields from the base class to the parent like this:

```
using System.Reflection;

public static ChildClass Clone(BaseClass b)
{
    ChildClass p = new ChildClass(...);

    // Getting properties of base class

    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(BaseClass).GetProperties();

    // Copy all properties to parent class

    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
    {
        if (pi.CanWrite)
            pi.SetValue(p, pi.GetValue(b, null), null);
    }

    return p;
}
```

An universal solution for any object can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4546412/2491281)

Comment: This should not work for reference-type properties. The new and old instances will use the same reference for reference-type properteis.

Comment: It would work in the cases you don't have nested properties or lists or both.

Answer (score 1):

To cast,  the **actual** object must be of a Type equal to or **derived** **from** the Type you are attempting to cast to...

or, to state it in the opposite way,  the Type you are trying to cast it to must be the same as, or a base class of, the actual type of the object.

if your actual object is of type *Baseclass*, then you can't cast it to a derived class Type...

Answer (score 1):

A variation on the serialization approach for those using ServiceStack:

```
var child = baseObject.ConvertTo<ChildType>();
```

or the more verbose:

```
var child = baseObject.ToJson().FromJson<ChildType>();
```

ServiceStack's serialization might be super fast and all, but clearly, this is not a solution for massive conversions in low-latency transfers, nor for highly complex types.  That's likely obvious to anyone using ServiceStack, but thought I'd clarify in anticipation of comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use derived class constructor with base class parameter.

```
class Base
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    public Base(Base baseClass)
    {
        Id = baseClass.Id;
        Name = baseClass.Name;
    }

    public Base(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}

class Child : Base
{
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
    public Child(Base baseClass) : base(baseClass) { }
}
```

Example of using:

```
Base realBase = new Base(1, "Base");
Child realChild = new Child(realBase);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).