# Enumerate and copy properties from one object to another object of same type

Tags: c#, .net, object, copy

I use a third party control which exports some data to different formats. The control has a property `ExportSettings`. But it is read-only.

I've to manually set its properties like

```
ctrl.ExportSettings.Paging = false;
ctr.ExportSettings.Background = Color.Red;
```

So I get the ExportSettings object from the user and I want to set it to the control.

How can I copy all its member values to the user control?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try reflection-based cloning:

```
private object CloneObject(object o)
{
    Type t = o.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();

    Object p = t.InvokeMember("", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance, 
        null, o, null);

    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
    {
        if (pi.CanWrite)
        {
            pi.SetValue(p, pi.GetValue(o, null), null);
        }
    }

    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

```
  static void CopyProperties(object dest, object src)
  {
   foreach (PropertyDescriptor item in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(src))
   {
    item.SetValue(dest, item.GetValue(src));
   } 
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`AutoMapper`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) :

Its very easy to use.

[Getting started with AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Something like this:

```
Type exportSettingType = ctrl.ExportSettings.GetType();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in exportSettingType.GetProperties())
{
    object value = property.GetValue(ctrl.ExportSettings, null);
    property.SetValue(secondControl.ExportSettings, value, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

see [How do you do a deep copy of an object in .NET (C# specifically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)