# How to cast childs of XmlElement to each other?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

**I have:**

```
public class Element : XmlElement
{
  // there is constructor, not important

  public string ElementSomething {get;set;}

}

public class Cat: Element {
  // there is constructor, not important

  public string CatSomething {get;set;}

}
```

**And now an epic question:**

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
  XmlElement xmlelem = new XmlElement (/*some params, not important */);
  Element elem = new Element (/*some params, not important*/);
  elem.ElementSomething = "Element";
  Cat catelem = new Cat(/*some params, not important*/);
  catelem .CatSomething = "Cat";  
}
```

**How to cast `elem` to `Cat` and back?**

```
Cat newcat = elem as Cat;
```

don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't - because it's *not* a `Cat`. This has nothing to do with XML at all - it's basic C#. You're trying to do the equivalent of:

```
object x = new Button();
string s = x as string;
```

What would you expect the content of `s` to be, if this worked?

You can't cast an object reference to a type which the object simply isn't an instance of. You could potentially write a conversion method to create a *new* object... but a better approach is usually to use composition rather than inheritance in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast a parent into a child class. See also this question: [Unable to Cast from Parent Class to Child Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988658/unable-to-cast-from-parent-class-to-child-class)

The other way around is easy:

```
 Cat cat = new Cat(...);
 var element = cat as Element;
```