# Why does my downcast fail in c#?

Tags: c#

I have three types:

1. `Patient`
2. `Inpatient : Patient`
3. `Outpatient : Patient`

I have a method that fills the base patient and all it's properties: `PatientRepository.FillPatient()` and returns a `Patient` object.

I then need to check and see what the `Patient` type is and downcast to either an `Outpatient` or `Inpatient`.

When I try to downcast, it is throwing `Unable to cast object of type 'Patient' to type 'Inpatient'.` This is a run-time error.

```
if (patient.Type == PatientType.Inpatient)
{
    var inpatient = (Inpatient)patient;             
    return inpatient;
}

public enum PatientType
{
    Inpatient, Outpatient
}
```

I have no idea why. Am I fundamentally doing something wrong here?

Comment: Is this a runtime or compile-time error?

Comment: Is Patient Type a property of your class? Or is it its Type? What is `PatientType`, an `enum` of Types?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729527/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-base-class-object-to-a-derived-class-reference-with-a

Comment: The key is FillPatient() It should create the correct Patient type not simply the base class

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988658/unable-to-cast-from-parent-class-to-child-class

Comment: If you have a base `Patient` instantiated as `new Patient()`, it is not one of the derived types and that is why your cast fails. Your cast is not changing the type of the object, but merely the type of the reference. If your object is not actually that type, the cast will fail! But since you didn't provide the code that actual deals with your base class, I am merely speculating as to what you have done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to assign a base class object to a derived class reference with an explicit typecast in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729527/is-it-possible-to-assign-a-base-class-object-to-a-derived-class-reference-with-a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *FillPatient* should return the specific class right way:

```
public static Patient FillPatient()
{
    if (something) {
        return new InPatient();
    }
    else {
        return new OutPatient();
    }
}
```

Then you can downcast it to a specific class

```
Patient patient = PaitentRepository.FillPatient();

if (patient is InPatient) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Note: most of the times when a class is the base for N other classes, that base class (*Patient* at your case) would be abstract.

Answer (score 1):

Because the question says "throwing" I will assume this is a runtime error. This in turn means that `PatientRepository.FillPatient()` returns an object of type `Patient` and somewhere contains `new Patient()`. You could mark the base class `Patient` as `abstract` and should then get some compiler errors.

If you want to cast to a subtype at some point `PatientRepository.FillPatient()` has to create instances of this subtypes. So instead of `new Patient()` you have to use `new Inpatient()`and `new Outpatient()` depending on the type of patient you are trying to populate.