# Avoid having to specify T type in a generic function

Tags: c#, function, casting, parent-child, generic-function

I've got this generic extending function that cast an object with a specific parent type as a child type (found the code here : [Unable to Cast from Parent Class to Child Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988658/unable-to-cast-from-parent-class-to-child-class)) :

```
public static U ParentToChild<T, U>(this T parent) {
    if(!typeof(U).IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)))
        throw new Exception(typeof(U).Name + " isn't a subclass of " + typeof(T).Name);
    var serializedParent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<U>(serializedParent);
}
```

So when I call this function I need to specify both Parent and Child class type like :

```
Child child = parent.ParentToChild<Parent, Child>();
```

Is there any way to avoid the 'Parent' precision ?

I would like to write this :

```
Child child = parent.ParentToChild<Child>();
```

Comment: No, there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make `object` the parameter type and remove the type parameter `T` altogether:

```
public static U ParentToChild<U>(this object parent) {
    // note how I used "parent.GetType()" instead of `typeof(T)`
    if (!typeof(U).IsSubclassOf(parent.GetType()))
        throw new Exception(typeof(U).Name + " isn't a subclass of " + parent.GetType().Name);
    var serializedParent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<U>(serializedParent);
}
```

By the way, your method isn't making full use of the generic type parameter `T` anyway. You could have used it as a constraint for `U`, avoiding a runtime check:

```
public static U ParentToChild<T, U>(this T parent) where U : T {
    //                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    var serializedParent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parent);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<U>(serializedParent);
}
```

So if you use `object` as the parameter, you lose this compile-time type checking.

Comment: Thanks ! 
I always forget how c# make it easy with the "where" keyword